# Removing a word in Java Program

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting my program to produce the exact output I would like it to. My program currently will remove any one instance of a string in a sentence the user inputs (Ex: Sentence- `Hello there`– String to be removed `Hello` and Output `there`).

What I would like to do is add something else so that the program will remove any and all instances of the string the user would like omitted (Ex: `Hello there there` in my current program, it would output `Hello there`. What I would like is it to simply print `Hello`). Can someone give me any idea on how to implement this. Thanks!

(Im also rather new to coding, so if you have an input on my code as is, please feel free to correct it)

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RemoveWord
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence;
    String word;

    public void removing()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
        sentence = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter a word you would like removed from the sentence");
        word = scan.nextLine();
        int start = sentence.indexOf(word), end=0;

        while(start!=-1)
        {
            sentence = sentence.substring(0, start) + sentence.substring(start+word.length());
            end = start+word.length();
            if(end>=sentence.length())
                break;
            start = sentence.indexOf(word, end);
        }
        System.out.println(sentence);
    }
}




public class RemoveWordR
{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    RemoveWord r1 = new RemoveWord();
    r1.removing();
    }//main


}//class
```

Comment: I can't check this code myself right now, but is there a reason to use everything related with `end`? Let's say you are not using `end`, so what happens? In your `while` loop you get all characters occuring in string before and after given word, then you look for next index of that word in the String. Why is that bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with end, because `indexOf(x,y)` check for occurrence of `x` after index `y`. It is [int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm)

```
while(start!=-1)
{
    sentence = sentence.substring(0, start) + sentence.substring(start+word.length());
    end = start+word.length();
    if(end>=sentence.length())
        break;
    start = sentence.indexOf(word, 0); //this line must be 0 or nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll()` method provided by a string should replace all occurrences of a given word in the string

Example:

```
sentence.replaceAll("there","")
```

or

```
sentence.removeAll("there")
```

Comment: Yes I know this, but our teacher does not want us to use this function. She wants us to understand the methods behind it before using it.

Comment: Hi, please use stringtokenizer to find the occurences of the word in the string and remove them.. Make sentence stringBuffer

Comment: While(sentence.indexof(word)){